# Texture atlas offset/repeat works for meshes but is ignored for point system particles

Tags: three.js, textures, webgl

I am using a texture atlas to hold a sequence of images. When mapping to a mesh with `MeshLambertMaterial`, using `Texture.offset` and `Texture.repeat` works beautifully to cut the subtexture out of the entire image.

However, using the exact same texture instance for a `PointCloudMaterial` renders the particles with the entire atlas, not just the selected subimage.

I tried to follow the three.js source code, but the documentation is scarce.

Is there a workaround for this better than using canvases to chop up the image?

Edit: As requested, a work-in-progress is available at http://jnm2.com/minesweeper/.

Comment: It is now called `PointCloud`. You can create your own `ShaderMaterial` to use with the `PointCloud` -- instead of `PointCloudMaterial`. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I may need a bit of introduction to shaders. Want to answer it?

Comment: I wrote a shader that does exactly what you suggest. It works for meshes. For PointCloud, it stays invisible and WebGL throws two INVALID_OPERATION errors each render: "drawArrays: Insufficient buffer size" and "vertexAttribPointer: A buffer must be bound."

Comment: Can you provide your code and a _simple_ live example?

Comment: Got it hosted if you'd like to see it. Also, the shader I wrote doesn't do lighting and the box edges look odd at extreme angles, so for meshes I'll go back to the LambertMaterial with texture offset and repeat. Still wonder why your suggestion doesn't work for PointSystems though.

Comment: Sorry. Apparently I pasted the incorrect code in my answer. Updated answer with fiddle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`THREE.PointCloudMaterial` has been renamed `THREE.PointsMaterial`.

`THREE.PointCloud` has been renamed `THREE.Points`.

---

You want to use a sprite sheet with your point cloud.

Instead of using `PointsMaterial` with your `Points`, you can create a custom `ShaderMaterial` instead.

The custom `ShaderMaterial` can access your sprite sheet and use a different sub-image for each particle.

To do so, use a shader like this one:

```html
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">

attribute vec2 offset;

varying vec2 vOffset;

void main() {

    vOffset = offset;

    gl_PointSize = 25.0;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

}
```

```html
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">

uniform sampler2D spriteSheet;
uniform vec2 repeat;

varying vec2 vOffset;

void main() {

    vec2 uv = vec2( gl_PointCoord.x, 1.0 - gl_PointCoord.y );

    vec4 tex = texture2D( spriteSheet, uv * repeat + vOffset );
    
    if ( tex.a < 0.5 ) discard;

    gl_FragColor = tex;

}

</script>
```

Then

```js
   // geometry
    geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
 
    // attributes
    var numVertices = 20;
    var positions = new Float32Array( numVertices * 3 ); // 3 coordinates per point
    var offsets = new Float32Array( numVertices * 2 ); // 2 coordinates per point

    geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
    geometry.setAttribute( 'offset', new THREE.BufferAttribute( offsets, 2 ) );

    // populate offsets
    var offset = new THREE.Vector2();

    for ( var i = 0, index = 0, l = numVertices; i < l; i ++, index += 3 ) {
 
        positions[ index ] = 100 * Math.random() - 50;
        positions[ index + 1 ] = 100 * Math.random() - 50;
        positions[ index + 2 ] = 100 * Math.random() - 50;

    }

   for ( var i = 0, index = 0, l = numVertices; i < l; i ++, index += 2 ) {

        offset.set( THREE.Math.randInt( 1, 3 ), THREE.Math.randInt( 2, 3 ) ).multiplyScalar( 0.25 ); // sprite sheet: 4 rows x 4 cols

        offsets[ index ] = offset.x;
        offsets[ index + 1 ] = offset.y;

    }

    // image
    image = document.createElement( 'img' );
    image.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) { texture.needsUpdate = true; } );

    // texture
    var texture = new THREE.Texture( image );

    // uniforms
    uniforms = {

        spriteSheet: { value: texture },
        repeat: { value: new THREE.Vector2( 0.25, 0.25 ) }

    };

    // material
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

        uniforms:       uniforms,
        vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent,
        transparent:    true

    } );

    // point cloud
    pointCloud = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );

    scene.add( pointCloud );
```

fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/nL0b6hco/

three.js r.137.4

Comment: could you say more about how this works? What role does the repeat uniform play here? That seems to indicate the size of each image cell -- is that right? Any elaboration or clarification you can provide would be very helpful!

Comment: @duhaime It is great you want to learn more, but the best way to learn is to build simple examples and experiment. Read the three.js docs and study the three.js examples. Do your own research. Only post a question after you have invested considerable effort, and then, ask a specific question about _your_ code. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley . Since posting the above I started experimenting and got this working--thanks very much for the example!