# Access the vertex index in the function passed to THREE.PointsMaterial.map

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a `THREE.Points` particle system and need to (slightly, per particle) modify the HTML5 Canvas texture that is returned from the function passed to `THREE.PointsMaterial.map`. Is it possible to access the index of the vertex the texture is being created for in that function so that, at the end, each particle/vertex is given a (slightly) different texture?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25372202/1461008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say

> Canvas texture that is returned from the function passed to
>   THREE.PointsMaterial.map

I am going to assume you mean something like [THIS](http://blog.2pha.com/threejs-easy-round-circular-particles).

If this is the case, then no, you can't access the vertex index. You are either going to have to create a different material and map for each vertex (which you probably don't want to do).
Or, create your own shader.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I mean. I need to learn how to work with shaders then. For the moment, I am only interested in changing the color of each vertex but setting vertexColors: true and passing a color that way seems to multiply the provided color with that of the Canvas texture which makes it difficult to control the outcome.

Comment: I have some basic shader demos [here](http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial). Firefox has a "shader edit" tab in its dev tools, I think you have to turn it on in the dev tools settings though. You could just look at the default point material shader and copy it making some adjustments.

Comment: Thank you **2pha**, I really enjoyed your examples, but I am getting the feeling that shaders won't solve my problem because I need to create a point cloud with each vertex having an extended 2d texture (a circle with radial color gradient, to be specific) that always faces the camera and renders fast enough for the number of points I have in my scene. Do you think this can still be achieved with shaders somehow (to have a spatially extended 2d texture per vertex that faces the camera at all times and accepts blending instructions as well)?

Comment: You can definitely do it with a shader. And, if all you need is a circle with a gradient, you may be better doing that within the shader too rather than using a texture map. hmm, I may have a go at it when I get a chance.