# texture Coordination in simple 2d world (THREE.Points) without UV

Tags: three.js, textures, shader, buffer-geometry

I want to load an image in THREE.Points and I'm using bufferGeometry without uv attribute and shaderMaterial 
can anyone explain me what is vu and why I need it? I have a 2d world (all points have z=0 position ) so can I use simple `vec2` instead of saving uv coordinations in attribute?

thanks in advance

Comment: @Rabbid76 now I had read it, it says that we need to exactly specify positions of the image (and I think you mean that my wish is impossible) but I'm using THREE.Points and they are like square but have just one `vec3` for position .
How could I simply show an image thousands of time in exact positions (in 2d World)

Comment: `THREE.Points` does not require UVs. See [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_billboards.html).

Comment: @WestLangley What about using it with ShaderMaterial?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25372202/1461008) you can find an example of `THREE.Points` using `ShaderMaterial`.

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you very much.
this was my answer
`vec2 uv = vec2( gl_PointCoord.x, 1.0 - gl_PointCoord.y );`