# Three.js sprite sheet offsets in THREE.Points

Tags: three.js, shader

I'm trying to get a sprite sheet texture in THREE.PointsMaterial to use offsets, so point particles can have different visuals.

Apparently this should be possible using THREE.ShaderMaterial, instead of PointsMaterial.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335967/texture-atlas-offset-repeat-works-for-meshes-but-is-ignored-for-point-system-par/25372202#25372202) seems to get so close to my solution, but the fiddle is broken and I'm having a hard time reconstructing it.
Shaders are new to me and I could use some help achieving the goal: get point particles to use different sections of a sprite sheet.
With a single image texture it's easy, like [this](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_sprites.html), but trying to use a sprite sheet with offsets is killing me ;)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335967/texture-atlas-offset-repeat-works-for-meshes-but-is-ignored-for-point-system-par/25372202#25372202) has been updated. It may help you.

Comment: Yes! Great, thanks.